# DOM monitoring in React App with Portals

Tags: reactjs

Now with Portals in React I can display a Component outside of SPA own DOM. This is cool. I have created a React App that puts a PayPal checkout button to any element with `class='put-button-here'` anywhere in index.html.

But this class should exist when the react SPA is downloaded and run. Is there any way I can watch for new DOM elements with `class='put-button-here'` and dynamical render a button there?

This is needed as there is no `class='put-button-here'` on the site home page where I want to link my JS file but it appears only under the 'Shop' menu.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a component will load, u can always do,

```
   let elem = document.querySelector('.put-button-here');
   if (elem){
      //if its present
      //create React Portal here
   }
```